# AWS REDSHIFT: ERROR Intermediate result row exceeds database block size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I inherited a freelance project. I know next to nothing about AWS and even less about Redshift. I would appreciate an

I keep getting that error when making a more complicated PostgreSQL query.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_014a622dfe AS ((SELECT * FROM prod.backend2 WHERE mail = 'Yes' AND marketing IN('MEDICINE')) UNION (SELECT * FROM prod.backend2 WHERE mail = 'Yes' AND marketing IN('AGRICULTURAL')));
```

ERROR:  Intermediate result row exceeds database block size

I googled it and it seems like it's due to a query being to 'big', this really makes no sense to me. But it's possible as the query is about 2960 chars.

Is there more to this error? How can I bypass it?

I did some research on redshift it seems to be designed for logging, this is being used for marketing; should I recommend switching to a RDS or another AWS product?

Comment: Edit your question and include the query and schema. Your error means that the intermediate row is wider than 1 MB. Modify your query to not return so much data in each row. You need to define what you mean by "marketing". You need to define what your data is, how big, how it is accessed, etc. There are times when a standard SQL server is better and there are times that products like Redshift are much better.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am only making a count query, I don't understand why that would be over 1mb. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You query is ??? your schema is ???, how can anyone review the problem without the data.

Comment: I am not sure hot to get the schema but I included the query.

Comment: select * from pg_table_def where tablename = 'prod.backend2' ;

Comment: I think your problem is that your table has a lot of columns. You are selecting all columns on both sides of your UNION and the combined width is more than 1 MB. Select only the columns that you actually need. Your table schema will tell you how many columns are in the table and the width (size) of each column.

Comment: I need all of the columns. Is this a PostgreSQL or Redshift issue?

Comment: The block size is a Redshift issue. However, I think that you will have the same problem with PostgreSQL server. Try selecting only one column to see if the query succeeds. This will verify my guess. If this is the case, you will need to redesign your query. However, you have not posted the schema so I am just guessing. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-query-tuning.html

Comment: please provide more info as at the moment this does not make sense. Exactly what does prod.backend2 look like? is it a redshift or a redshift-spectrum external table? what is the definition of the table?